# AWS Auto Scaling Multiple Custom AMIs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I have several custom AMIs running which I would like to control as a group, i.e. automatically spin them up and tear them down at predefined times. They are different amis rather than multiples of the same ami. Is this possible with the auto scaling API?

Answer (score 2):

let's say you want to create three instances, you can create them via individual calls to the CLI ec2-run-instances, such as

ec2-run-instances ami-1a2b3c4d -k gsg-keypair (more params etc)

ec2-run-instances ami-7d2b3c55 -k gsg-keypair (more params etc)

ec2-run-instances ami-8d2b3c55 -k gsg-keypair (more params etc)

retrieving the instance id from each call. then tag that instance as part of the group:

ec2-create-tags i-bf72dbd2 --tag "purpose=xyz_pdq"   (for each of the three changing the instance id on each call)

then, later, you can retrieve a list of instances with that tag by calling

ec2-describe-tags --filter "resource-type=instance" --filter "key=purpose" --filter "value=xyz_pdq"

iterate thru the list and terminate those instances

Comment: But there is no clean way to do this using the auto scaling API?

Comment: i can't see any examples of creating multiple ami's in one auto scaling group. but you can certainly have multiple groups with individual group and plans for each, and base those AMI's (tag those initial AMI's) with a common group TAG so you can clobber them all at once like stated above after you reset their max value to 0

Comment: Yeah that seems like the only way to go alright, thanks for the input

Comment: sorry cant think of anything cleaner :>

Comment: I think it would be a useful feature for them to bring in. I'm sure there are plenty of people running several custom instances, each doing a specific task, that they would like to easily tear down Friday evening and spin back up Monday morning.

Comment: @robocode - Good point, but given [AWS CloudFormation](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/) already allows to _create and manage a collection of related AWS resources, provisioning and updating them in an orderly and predictable fashion_, I'd not expect this feature to be implemented for [Auto Scaling](http://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/) itself anymore; unfortunately [CloudFormation support for Auto Scaling schedules and suspend](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=419172) is pending as well though, albeit at least likely to happen at some point.